# Query with variable tablename

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I don't know why I keep bumping into these, but I have a small problem with a stored procedure. The only special in it is the variable Tablename:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ProdTijdCompare

@TABLENAME SYSNAME,
@scanner    nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = 'select SUM(tijd) from ' + @TABLENAME + 'where Scanner = @scanner'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
END
GO
```

The error I'm getting when executing in SSMM:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '='.

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always quote table names in dynamic SQL to avoid SQL Injection (cf [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms176114.aspx))

Second, supply the `@scanner` parameter to the `sp_executesql` procedure as you can see in the sample below:

```
SELECT @SQL = 'select SUM(tijd) from ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME) + ' where Scanner = @scanner'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@scanner NVARCHAR(50)', @scanner;
```

Comment: Using the above sql, I get my results.

Answer (score 2):

You need a space between `@TableName` and `where`:

```
SELECT @SQL = 'select SUM(tijd) from ' + @TABLENAME + ' where Scanner = @scanner';
```

This type of error is incredibly obvious if you just print out the SQL before running it.